# CMS Bitrix does not load script

Tags: javascript, html, css, bitrix

In console writes:

```
uncaught reference error.
```

Please tell me, where is error?

```
<script>
    $('select').selectric({
    maxHeight: 200
    });
    $.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried putting the `$.noConflict();` *above* the `$('select') ...` ??

Comment: @zak not. 

$.noConflict();  to avoid conflicts with other scripts.

What do you think is the mistake?

Comment: I think the uncaught reference is the `select` itself .. Because 1) the library isn't loading correctly -- or 2) the `noConflict` isn't functioning as expected ..  If I were you, I'd put the `noConflict` right after the library loads.  also look in your dev tools and make sure that the library istelf is loading, and to further your troubleshooting, click on the uncaught reference .. It should take you to the line of code in question.

Comment: there is a chance that jquery is loaded after your script executed, could you test this idea?

Answer (score 0):

I thik this code can avoid error:

```
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    $(function () {
        "use strict";

        if (typeof($.selectric) === "function") {
            $("select").selectric({
                maxHeight: 200
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```